# Updated to 14.04, Mutt only S/MIME? Whence PGP/MIME?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, mutt, email-client

I might be going senile.  Using the stock Mutt on 13.04 I was able to something like (E)ncrypt (from memory) and have it use GnuPG.  With 14.04, the Mutt 1.5.21 that came with the upgrade, there's an 'S' on the message menu seems to only twiddle S/MIME settings, not PGP/MIME.

Am I missing something? What is the natural Ubuntu-way to get PGP/MIME working? I'd rather not go back to in-line encoding!

Sourcing /etc/Muttrc.d/pgp.rc does not seem to do anything. There's bunch of mentions of gnupg and pgp in the mutt -v output.  In fact the documentation makes no mention of 'native' GnuPG handling, only commands to configure.

Did Ubuntu at one stage have a more GnuPG-friendly default configuration perhaps?

All the searches I do seem to only hit pages where people are trying to get S/MIME working.

(I wish people would stop trying to make S/MIME happen.  S/MIME is not going to happen.)

Cheers.